# Test auth failure with FaceID and TouchID on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, lacontext

I want to test faceId/touchId mechanism in my app.
I have following:

```
func auth(){

    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {

      var reason: String = Strings.Common.unknownBiometryTip.value
      if BiometricService.biometricType() == .touchID {
        reason = Strings.Common.touchIDEnterTip.value
      }
      if BiometricService.biometricType() == .faceID {
        reason = Strings.Common.faceIDEnterTip.value
      }

       context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason) { [weak self] (success, error) in
        print("error \(error)")
        if let error = error as? LAError, error.errorCode == Int(kLAErrorUserCancel) {
          self?.cancelTapped?()
          return
        }

        if success {
          self?.authSucceed?()
        }
        else {
          self?.authFailure?()
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      print("Touch ID neither Face ID not available")
    }
  }
```

I actually can't test `authFailure` block, because when i hit "not-matching face" button in XCode, it shows up pin entry view, and look like anything i type in handled as "correct".

I actually want callback anytime user have "wrong" face/touchId/pin entry attempt, but i can't figure out how to get it.

Comment: You should try in real device.

Comment: @SagarChauhan i should have both with touch id and new iPhone X versions?